# Protocol used by the Azure Storage explorer to connect to Azure storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-files, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-explorer

Can someone please help to find the protocol used by the Azure Storage Explorer to connect to Azure storage??
is it SMB or REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage Explorer (ASE) is a wrapper around azcopy command tool.

[image: You can copy the azcopy command from here!]

Here is a sample of azcopy command I pasted into the notepad

[image: azcopy command]

and Azcopy internally uses REST api.

In order to capture all the REST api calls going out you can also use fiddler tool.

Follow the instruction from the link below and you should be able to see them.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/web-connection-fiddler

So the order is ASE uses -> azcopy uses -> REST API.

or you can also find the azcopy logs  at this location for individual session at "%USERPROFILE%.azcopy"

Comment: Not 100% correct. Storage Explorer uses azcopy for performing bulk operations like uploads and downloads etc. For all other operations it makes use of the SDK which is a wrapper over REST API.

Comment: Hmm is there a documentation which says this @GauravMantri ? I haven't heard anyone say this, will correct it / add to it later.

Comment: Simply look at the features of azcopy and Storage Explorer and you will see that Storage Explorer has lot more features than azcopy. How do you think that is possible if your Storage Explorer is built on top of just azcopy. Also go to the Storage Explorer installation directory and look for package.json file. You will find all storage SDKs in there as dependencies. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

It is REST.

Storage Explorer makes use of Storage SDKs for JavaScript which are wrapper over REST API.